# How to describe "ascribing the actions of the few to the many"? What kind of thinking is that?

Tags: single-word-requests

Racism being the classic example, but there are many. ACAB (all cops are bastards) is another. I thought reductionist might work here but it doesn't. "Lazy" is too simplistic. "Collectivist" doesn't work either.

Comment: That's not a reduction, that's a generalization. And that's the word for it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Please make “generalization” an answer. I like it. I wish I had remembered this word, myself.

Comment: Composition fallacy - in the linked question - is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

“Stereotyping” seems to be the most often used term. For instance, saying, “White people are racist”, or “Cops are bastards” is attributing very extreme attributes to a collective of people due to the overbearing nature of the attributes. The effects of a few with these attributes overshadows the many that do not have these attributes.

Conversely, the majority of stereotypes are true to a small extent or for a small percentage of individuals. The stereotype just overemphasizes and broadly exaggerates the truth to fit it’s application to the majority of the individuals. Regardless if it is true for a specific individual.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389113/technical-term-for-associating-a-group-with-the-actions-of-a-few

Answer (score 0):

The most general term for this is [**generalization**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generalization):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : a general statement, law, principle, or proposition
>     // made broad *generalizations* about women
>     // Often, physical features such as skin tone are used to guide attitudes, emotions and behaviors that can influence interactions between people of different races and lead to oversimplified *generalizations* about a person’s character.
> — Rashawn Ray, *The Conversation*, "The killing of Ahmaud Arbery highlights the danger of jogging while black," 7 May 2020

---

The word can also be applied to things as well as people.

For instance, the following might be said:

> Most stores are open for business on Mondays, but it's a *generalization* to say that all stores are open then.

---

Unlike *racism* and *sexism*, which have implicit negative meanings, *generalization* can be used in a neutral or even positive way, depending on the context:

> "I know you're not familiar with this particular bomb. But you've disarmed enough of other types. You're going to have to make a *generalization*."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389113/technical-term-for-associating-a-group-with-the-actions-of-a-few